# Tengo un problema con una exprecion en simulink matlab

Tags: matlab

Nos estan solicitando replicar este ejercicio en simulink y probarlo, pero tengo un error con la expresion senalada
[image: Expecificamente en C.s]

Esta es mi replica del ejemplo

[image: Si se dan cuenta aunque uso un transfer FCN no se ve igual]

Estos son los parametros que le doy a ese componente:
[image: Y aqui es donde ciento que hago algo mal]

Eh aqui el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudiera horientar sobre lo que sucede y como seria la manera de corregirlo lo agradeceria un monton.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre solucionar efectivamente estaba definiendo los parametros mal, esta es la manera correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]